# VBA macro freeze on locked screen

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, windows-task-scheduler, office-automation

I'm using automate excel vba macro send emails. I want to set it in Task Scheduler to make it automate. When screen is not locked everything works perfect, but when set Task Scheduler and lock the screen the macro stop at below moment. It doesn't return any errors. It just stop and shows blank new email window in outlook app.

Do you know if there is any option to fix that?

```
Dim xInspect As Object
Dim pageEditor As Object

Set xInspect = OutMail.GetInspector
Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor

Worksheets("Email_Sender_Body").Range("K1:K" & row_count_body).Copy

pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
.Display

Set pageEditor = Nothing
Set xInspect = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to set it in Task Scheduler to make it automate

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

As a possible workaround you may consider using the Open XML SDK if you deal with open XML documents only, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information. Or you may also consider third-party components designed for the server-side execution.

A low-level API on which Outlook is based can be used from a Windows service - Extended MAPI. Or in case of Exchange server accounts you may use `EWS` or `Graph API`. See [Explore the EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange) for more information.